# Parsing between different time formats to determine day or night

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, time

I'm creating a webpage that display current data from a weather api. For a given location I want to determine if it is night, day, or within an hour of sunrise or sunset.

The API returns the current time in the location in the format: "Tue, 12 Apr 2016 04:00 PM EDT"

It returns the sunset and sunrise times in the format:  "7:00am"

I was able to parse the current time with jQuery using Date.parse(); but this will not work for the short format times. I tried using data.js which parsed the short format times, but not the long format. I wasn't able to combine the two parsing formats. Any suggestions on how to get these times into a common format and compare them to find the time of day?

Comment: what your expected inputs and outputs?

Comment: can you provide jquery code?

Comment: Either you need to write a own parsing code, or you can thing about something like [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) which a nice support for [parsing](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) different formats